# MVC Can't use certain JS Libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I added a new js library to my project (typeahead.bundle.js) and whenever I try and call any functions it claims they don't exist. It seems that its looking in jQuery instead of my library:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).typeahead is not a function
(anonymous function) @ Create:50
x.Callbacks.c @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21
x.Callbacks.p.fireWith @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21
x.extend.ready @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21q @ jquery-1.10.2.min.js:21
```

I've also found this issue with jQuery-ui.

Relevant usage:

```
<script src="/Scripts/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $( "#MemberSearch" ).typeahead({ //error line
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Operations/AutoCompleteMember",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Member, value: item.Member };
                        }))

                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

...

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Member Search", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBox("MemberSearch", "", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control btn-group" })
                <button type="button" onclick="" class="btn btn-group" aria-label="Left Align">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Have you loaded `typeahead` library? Error clearly suggest not.

Comment: @Satpal Is <script src="/Scripts/typeahead.bundle.js"></script> not enough? In what other way would I load the lib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install [typeahead nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twitter.Typeahead/), add link to script `<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>` after jquery included and then it works

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help, when I view the source it removes the "~" and I still get the error.

Comment: @KenLund, I've just added typehead nuget package in my solution, inserted link to js, pasted your code and it works! :) But I use bootstrap3-typeahead.js